# How to access Docker instance

Tags: docker

I deployed an open source online code editor on my local machine. According to the documentation provided by the provider; Judge0 my `instance of Judge0 CE v1.13.0 is now available at http://<IP ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVER>:2358.`

[image]

Attached an image of my log from Docker. To clarify my question I would like to access the instance of Judge0 on my local browser. I have tried `https://localhost:2358/` to no avail.

**Update**
Here's a link to the dockerfile: https://github.com/judge0/judge0/blob/master/Dockerfile

and the commands I ran

```
cd judge0-v1.13.0
docker-compose up -d db redis
sleep 10s
docker-compose up -d
sleep 5s
```

Comment: Post Dockerfile and how you are running your container

Comment: @RakeshGupta by Dockerfile you are referring to this: https://github.com/judge0/judge0/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#deployment-procedure

Comment: @Emm It looks like your Dockerfile is here: https://github.com/judge0/judge0/blob/master/Dockerfile Please confirm that's the right URL.  Also note that although the Dockerfile exposes port 2358, the Docker instance is _not_ your local machine. In general, you'll need to know the address where the Docker image is running, but unless you're doing port-forwarding you haven't described, `localhost` is _not_ the Docker instance.  From your description, try `http://<IP ADDRESS OF YOUR SERVER>:2358`. Also, text is preferable to screenshots.  Also consider adding tags for `judge0` or other tools.

Comment: @SarahMesser Do you mean right URL as in the URL I should be running to access the Docker image or are you asking me to confirm if the github url I sent is the right one?

Comment: Please edit the question and include the Dockerfile directly in the question; a GitHub link in a comment doesn't necessarily make it clear what you're asking.  It also looks like you might have included a screen shot of some sort, but including the plain-text output of your container and the actual command you used to launch it will be much clearer.

Answer (score -1):

usually it should be on localhost if you are running locally